# How to pair bluetooth device without pin?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

Android requires something to be entered in PIN field to enable OK button.
Device requires that nothing is entered in PIN field to successfully pair (works on Windows).

Any solutions?

P.S. the more I use Android the less I like it!

Comment: Yes, it's not above. It's below. To those who know the solution Android version doesn't matter. Device doesn't matter either (firmware is latest). This is an old problem with many bug reports to BTS.

Comment: More information is definitely required, such as: Android device Make/Model & OS version, Bluetooth Device make/model.

Answer (score 1):

You say it's not connecting to your computer through buletooth anymore/at all. You said it is below android 4.2.1. If your device is android 4.2.x or higher (x being anything) then that may be your problem there since that was the update where google rewrote the android Bluetooth stack. I would recommend downloading another bluetooth stack on your pc (try the Toshiba Bluetooth stack: http://www.support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3461138 ) which should give you more Bluetooth device drivers. Once you do that then you shouldn't have a problem connecting your android device to your pc over Bluetooth. Also would like to mention that you should check your Bluetooth dongle/adapter on your pc. I would suggest a bluetooth 4.0 for compatibility reasons, but a 2.0+ should work just fine (might be slower though). Hope that helps